# How do I handle quaternions?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have read many tutorials and publications on the subject; however, I am still unclear on how to use them for causing rotation. I am working on an AUV, and I see that quaternions seem to be fundamental to motion. Are there any recommended learning materials that could help me to get a complete understanding of using them with robot motion? I am very new to ROS, so I greatly appreciate any response.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259223/how-do-i-handle-quaternions?/) by [mclambchops](https://answers.ros.org/users/30018/mclambchops/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2017-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are at least three popular ways to specify a rotation in 3-D.

- 3x3 rotation matrix (or 4x4 matrix in homogeneous coördinates)
- Euler angles (such as angles of roll, pitch, and yaw, often X, Y, and Z axis rotations, though there are many variations on Euler angles)
- Quaternions (specifies an axis of rotation and an angle of rotation about that axis)

The main thing to know about a quaternion is that it encodes two things in a 4-tuple: 1) an axis of rotation (a 3-D vector), and 2) an angle of rotation, measured as the counter-clockwise rotation in radians about that vector (right-hand rule). This can represent any 3-D rotation using four elements, only slightly more memory than used by Euler angles, and considerably less than the matrix representation.

The 4-tuple quaternion mixes the axis of rotation and angle in a strange way. Let's say the axis of rotation is the vector `<x, y, z>` and the angle of rotation is `theta`, measured as the right-hand rotation in radians about `<x, y, z>`. Then the quaternion that represents that rotation is:

```
<cos(theta/2), x*sin(theta/2), y*sin(theta/2), z*sin(theta/2)>
```

That's really all there is to it, it's just a fairly compact representation of an arbitrary rotation. Quaternions have several advantages over Euler angles and matrix representations.

- More compact than matrix representations.
- Can perform rotations with fewer multiplications, and mathematically more stable.
- Can interpolate rotations component-by-component to generate intermediate states smoothly.
- No "gimbal lock" problem. (Google this.)

(Note: There are actually multiple forms of quaternion representations, but only one in ROS.)

---

Originally posted by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) with karma: 1563 on 2017-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-04-14**:
One small point: There are libraries in ROS that cover all the computation of quaternions (transforming them to or from rotation matrices for example) so you do not need to implement a quaterion-quaternion multiplication by hand. I can't transform a point with a quat by hand and still work with it.

**Comment by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) on 2017-04-14**:
Yes, certainly. I didn't mean to imply that one should implement the manipulations. I was just trying to demystify quaternions a little. (The algebra definition using i, j, k can be daunting, whereas if you think about axis of rotation and angle they aren't mysterious at all.)

**Comment by [mclambchops](https://answers.ros.org/users/30018/mclambchops/) on 2017-04-14**:
Thanks for your responses. This definitely demystifies things for me.

**Comment by [eugene.katsevman](https://answers.ros.org/users/29247/eugene.katsevman/) on 2017-04-14**:
please, accept this answer then

**Comment by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) on 2017-04-17**:
Yes, please accept the answer. It's easier for others to find good answers if they are accepted.